# Iterating Function without Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, fetch, iteration, for-of-loop

Here it must fetch every url inside `<li>` tags with `disc` type in initial webpage. The html of initial webpage is roughly this:

```html
<body>
  <li type="disc">
    <a href="url1">Lorem.</a>
    <a href="url2">Dolor</a>
    <a href="LAST_URL3">In!</a>
  </li>
  <li type="disc">
    <a href="url">Accusantium.</a>
    <a href="url">Dolor</a>
    <a href="url">Eveniet!</a>
  </li>
  <li type="disc">
    <a href="url">Asperiores?</a>
    <a href="url">Dolor</a>
    <a href="url">Suscipit!</a>
  </li>
  <li type="disc">
    <a href="url">Excepturi?</a>
    <a href="url">Dolor</a>
    <a href="url">Temporibus!</a>
  </li>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```js
    const w = await mani.metax.get(work).then(r => r.json())
    const url = w.source
    const response = await fetch( + url)
    const html = await response.text()

    async function parse() {
        const parser = new DOMParser()
        const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html')

        booksNames = w.booksNames.split(', ')
        const booksList = url.includes('bible') ? doc.querySelectorAll('div.arm') : doc.querySelectorAll('li[type="disc"]')
        for (const book of booksList) {
            let bookObj = {"name": booksNames[0], "type": "7d998386-e38f-4d73-97f3-db9f1d7641d8-bf1523bf-09f1-4822-b546-9a10a8263ceb"}
            let bookObjStr = JSON.stringify(bookObj); booksNames.shift()
            let uuid = await mani.metax.save(bookObjStr)
            const b = await mani.metax.get(uuid).then(r => r.json()); b.uuid = uuid; b.chapters = []

            const chaptersList = Array.from(book.querySelectorAll('a'));

            let hrefsList = chaptersList.map(({href}) => ({href: href.replace('https://realschool.am:542/db/', url), done:false, doc:""}));
            let current
            const getData = async () => {
                if (hrefsList.length === 0) {
                    let versesList = Array.from(current.doc.querySelectorAll('table:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(1)'))
                    let chapObj = {"type": "4e680ac1-c1ac-408b-af50-103843ad1054-7b348fbb-0890-418d-b176-e090b76a8c50"}
                    let chapObjStr = JSON.stringify(chapObj)
                    let chapUUID = await mani.metax.save(chapObjStr)
                    const c = await mani.metax.get(chapUUID).then(r => r.json()); c.uuid = chapUUID; c.verses = []
                    c.name = versesList[0].innerText.trim().replace('``', '').slice(4); versesList.shift()
                    for (let verse of versesList) {
                        let text = verse.innerText.trim().replace('``', '')
                        let obj = {"name": text.split(' ')[0], "type": "06408198-7666-43f4-b2eb-6de5715434f9-f801e312-0957-4429-871b-7d448364c65c"}
                        let objStr = JSON.stringify(obj)
                        let verseUUID = await mani.metax.save(objStr)
                        const v = await mani.metax.get(verseUUID).then(r => r.json()); v.uuid = verseUUID; v.text = text
                        await mani.metax.update(verseUUID, JSON.stringify(v))
                        c.verses.push(verseUUID)
                    }
                    await mani.metax.update(chapUUID, JSON.stringify(c))
                    b.chapters.push(chapUUID) // Adding new object in a collection
                } else {
                    current = hrefsList[0];
                    const res = fetch(current.href).then(response => response.text()).then(text => {
                        const parser = new DOMParser()
                        current.doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html')
                    }).then(() => {
                        current.done = true;
                        console.log(current.href,'parsed successfully');
                        hrefsList = hrefsList.filter(({done}) => !done);
                        setTimeout(getData, 2000); // try next (or again)
                    })
                }
            }
            getData();

                let versesList = Array.from(doc.querySelectorAll('table:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(1)'))
                let chapObj = {"type": "4e680ac1-c1ac-408b-af50-103843ad1054-7b348fbb-0890-418d-b176-e090b76a8c50"}
                let chapObjStr = JSON.stringify(chapObj)
                let chapUUID = await mani.metax.save(chapObjStr)
                const c = await mani.metax.get(chapUUID).then(r => r.json()); c.uuid = chapUUID; c.verses = []
                c.name = versesList[0].innerText.trim().replace('``', '').slice(4); versesList.shift()
            //}
            await mani.metax.update(uuid, JSON.stringify(b))
            w.books.push(uuid) // Adding new object in a collection

            await mani.metax.update(work, JSON.stringify(w)).then(r => alert("New book complete"))
        }
    }
```

But what it actually does is fetching every url from only first `<li>`, and after fetching the `LAST_URL3` it causes `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerText')`. So it seems it tries to fetch more urls from `<li>` and as there are no more it just fetches `undefined`. It must iterate and start to fetch urls already from second `<li>` but it doesn't. Even more, if we'll output to console any test message after calling the function `getData()`, it will be outputed and will be outputed before `(some url) parsed successfully` messages which are outputed after successful fetch of every url. Mustn't test message be outputed after `parsed successfully` if we called function earlier than outputed test? And if it doesn't stuck at function and moves on to the rest loop content, then why loop doesn't iterate?

Comment: Notice that `await getData();` does not wait for `setTimeout(getData, 2000);`. Instead of recursion, try writing an actual loop

Comment: So this way:
```const chaptersList = Array.from(book.querySelectorAll('a'));
for (chapter of chaptersList) {
  const href = chapter.getAttribute('href').replace('../book/', '')
  let res = []
  let ref = url + href
  const response = await fetch(corsProxy + ref)
  console.log(response)
  const html = await response.text()
  const parser = new DOMParser()
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html')
}
console.log('parsed')```
But it every time parses links of only some <li>s, like 2 <li>s or 3, or all <li>s...